# How to output a forloop in a string?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to output data object with multiple properties into a string within phpmailer how do I achieve this?

```
function sendMailTo($mail, $data, $subject_, $toEmail) {
    $body = 'all data:' foreach ($data as $obj) {
        $obj->property;
    }

    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->AddAddress($toEmail);
    $mail->FromName = $data->inputName;
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->Subject = $subject_;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddReplyTo($toEmail, $data->inputName);
    $mail->send();
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? Why do you want to echo something with that method?

Comment: echo was a typo shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a bit nonsensical, unless `$data` is really an array of objects, each having a property called `property`.

If you want to extract all the properties of an object, iterate over them, because [PHP objects are iterable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php).

Also there's no need to use a local variable; assemble the string directly into `$mail->Body`:

```
$mail->Body = "All data:\r\n";
foreach ($data as $property => $value) {
    $mail->Body .= "$property = $value\r\n";
}
```

I've assumed that you want both the property names and values.

(and you can remove the later line that says `$mail->Body = $body;`)

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation and add values to `$body` variable:

```
$body = 'all data:';
foreach ($data as $obj) {
    $body .= $obj->property;
}
```

Comment: remember to finish it off with  echo $body;

Comment: Body should be set to `$mail->Body = $body;` not echoed.

Comment: true, that is apparent from the code. The question is how to output it though, so in that strict sense it would be echoed. But yeah, in this case you're right.

Comment: Echo was my fault. Thanks for your answer!